# Query count, sum, with condition in one query with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table in a mysql database :

```
TABLE rating
| id         (int, primary)
| id_company (int, index)
| state      (enum: 'waiting','done','refuse')
| rating     (int between 1 and 5)
```

I want to get this stats for one id_company :

- number lines
- number lines with state=done
- sum rating
- sum rating with state=done

For this i have 2 queries (exemple with id_company=2) :

```
SELECT COUNT(1) as `nbr`, SUM(`rating`) as `total` FROM `rating` WHERE `id_company`=2
SELECT COUNT(1) as `nbr`, SUM(`rating`) as `total` FROM `rating` WHERE `id_company`=2 AND `state`='done'
```

But it is possible to make an unique query to get this stats ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `nbr1`, 
       SUM(`rating`) as `total1`,
       SUM(`state`='done') as `nbr2`, 
       SUM(CASE 
              WHEN `state`='done' THEN `rating` 
              ELSE 0 
           END) as `total2`  
FROM `rating` 
WHERE `id_company`=2
```

Comment: Well done, thanks. Why not let id_company in the where clause ? it works too.

Comment: @Jeremy Yes you are right. The `id_company` predicate should also be used in the `WHERE` clause because it makes the query run faster.

Comment: why you save 'id_company=2` in cases while adding `where` ?

Comment: @spash58 i remove it in my query, it's indeed not necessary

Comment: @splash58 OK, I've edit my query to make it cleaner.

Comment: Ok. it's better to save the answer in such edition :)